# Insert query is not inserting data in my table but gives no error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on SQL Server 2008. I have written my insert query, but it's not inserting the data into the table and also not giving any error.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my query?

Here is my query:

```
insert into sc_trln
( doc_ref
, doc_type
, item
, qty
, unit
, factor
, unit_cost
, cost_per_unit
, item_tot
, item_name
)
select 'SA/000091'
,      'SA'
,      '006824'
,      '-2.000'
,      'PCS   '
,      '1.000'
,      '0.6446'
,      '0.6446'
,      '-1.2892'
,      'ALALAI ORANGE JAMS 465GM'
```

Comment: Made query readable.

Answer (score 0):

Change your syntax from SELECT to VALUES if you're using fixed values. Also wrap your values in brackets like this;

```
INSERT INTO sc_trln (doc_ref, doc_type, item, qty, unit, factor, unit_cost, cost_per_unit, item_tot, item_name)
VALUES ('SA/000091', 'SA', '006824', '-2.000', 'PCS   ', '1.000', '0.6446', '0.6446', '-1.2892', 'ALALAI ORANGE JAMS 465GM')
```

Comment: while it is not as pretty as using values for a single entry there is nothing wrong with OPs syntax

Answer (score 0):

The first form does not specify the column names where the data will be inserted, only their values:

**INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);**

The second form specifies both the column names and the values to be inserted:

**INSERT INTO table_name(column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);**

Just make the required changes and it should work:)

Comment: there is nothing wrong with his syntax, column names are not necessary when using select like he does.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, but there is nothing wrong with the method you are showing but you are treating everything including obviously numeric columns as strings so SQL will convert them back to the appropriate datatype.

The issue likely lies somewhere else in your code, perhaps this never gets called because of a IF THEN control flow, or transaction gets rolled back in error trapping, or because the transaction is never committed...or??  you need to post more of the code to determine the issue.

While the Others show appropriate syntax to insert a single value your syntax is NOT incorrect, other than treating everything as a string.

Here is an example almost exactly copied and pasted from your syntax

```
DECLARE @sc_trln AS TABLE (doc_ref VARCHAR(50),doc_type VARCHAR(50),item VARCHAR(50),qty DECIMAL(15,4),unit VARCHAR(50)
    ,factor DECIMAL(15,4),unit_cost DECIMAL(15,4),cost_per_unit DECIMAL(15,4),item_tot DECIMAL(15,4),item_name VARCHAR(100))

insert into @sc_trln(doc_ref,doc_type,item,qty,unit,factor,unit_cost,cost_per_unit,item_tot,item_name)
select'SA/000091','SA','006824','-2.000','PCS   ','1.000','0.6446','0.6446','-1.2892','ALALAI ORANGE JAMS 465GM'

SELECT *
FROM
    @sc_trln
```